# Numeric field just accept number and `,`

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can change this numeric(normal number formatting) js code as that just accept number and `,`, mean don't accept word or character(like: `-`, `=`, `+`,`!`, and `...`) just accept number and `,`. How is it?

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/fQb9X/

```
$(document).delegate('input.numeric:text', 'keyup', function () {
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
});
```

Comment: You might find life easier if you avoid reinventing the wheel and used well established and tested solutions to validation like http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote something just like this recently:

```
var oldnumber='';
var $ctrl=$('input[name=passport_number]');
$ctrl.focusout(function () {
    if (isFinite($ctrl.val()) || $ctrl.val()==',') {
        oldnumber=$ctrl.val();
    } else {
        $ctrl.attr('value',oldnumber);
    }
});
```

Basically, if you type in a valid answer, it remembers that value. If you write anything but a number or a ',', the field is set back to its previous valid value.

My solution is decently short and pretty darn clean if you ask me. It checks if it is a number, if not, it denies your entry.

**EDIT**

If you want it to happen while you type, try this:

```
$('input').bind('keyup change',function(){
    var v = parseInt($(this).val());
    $(this).val((isNaN(v) && v!=',')?'':v);
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @EmmyCharles What?  You asked a question just like your last one, I just copied and pasted my last answer and modified it to support `,'s`...

Comment: I give answer from it question, i have new question about code normal number formatting that just typed number and `,`.

Comment: @Dade: if you bind this to 'keyup', and the user moves the caret within the text field and types, won't the caret be moved back to the end of the field?

Comment: @EmmyCharles I'm sorry, I can't understand anything you are trying to say.

Comment: @DadeLamkins you see this: http://jsfiddle.net/fQb9X/ , you can type in field word or character`=!@#$%$^&*()_+?><` and etc. i want just typed number and `,`(like: `1,111,111`). understand?